# Refresh the parent page and open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am opening a SSRS report from C# asp.net.After opening the report I need to refresh the parent page.
I have given the url to the report directly in the code.

In the code behind,

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('" + url +
"','_blank')", true);

It opens the page in the new tab.But I would need to refresh the parent page.
Please let me know if I could refresh the parent page after opening the SSRS link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `location.reload();` to your event handler

Comment: I got a message 'To display a webpage again the webpage needs to resend the information you have previously submitted.' location.href = location.href worked.Thanks